# UIActivityIndicatorView freeze when using custom segue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview, uistoryboardsegue

i need help here, i'm using a custom segue to push a view controller to another view controller.

when pushed using cutom segue, the uiactivityindicator will not animate automatically when view loaded.

however if i used the push method on the storyboard, the uiactivityindicator animate automatically.

what i had done wrong ?

```
-(void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceVC = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationVC = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    [UIView transitionWithView:sourceVC.navigationController.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        [sourceVC.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:NO];
                        //NSLog(@"count of subview %i", [self.view.subviews count]);
                    }
                    completion:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIViewController *sourceVC = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *destinationVC = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

[UIView transitionFromView:sourceVC.view toView:destinationVC.view duration:.5 options:0 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  [sourceVC.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:NO];
}];
```

The `-pushViewController:animated:` should not be putted in the animation block but the completion block.

Comment: hi xan, thanks for the reply...it works but i lost the animations. any workaround ?

Comment: Set transition option such as `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` for the option parameter then it should work.